# creating variables from data after using the fold command

Tags: bash, fold

My main goal is to set up variables which are taken from a string which can be of various lengths. Each variable must contain 4 digits from the string (ie `var_1 =` digits 1-4, `var_2 =` digits 5-8 etc). By using the `fold -w4` command I can get the string into blocks of 4.
For example:

```
string = 1234567898765432
fold -w4:
1234
5678
9876
5432
```

Rather than manually create the variables by copying the data, can anyone suggest how I can get Bash to automatically create variables for each block of 4 that is created?

I have searched Google and even tried ChatGPT. The suggestion given doesn't seem to work:

```
# Get the length of the input string
    length=${#input_string}

# Loop through the string in steps of 4 characters
    for (( i=0; i<$length; i+=4 )); do
        # Extract 4 characters starting from position i
        substring="${input_string:i:4}"

        # Create a variable with the extracted substring
        var_name="var_$((i/4 + 1))"
        declare "$var_name=$substring"
    done

# Print the created variables
    echo "Created variables:"
    declare -p | grep -E '^declare -\w+ var_[0-9]+='
```

All that happens is I get the "Created variables" written to the terminal.

Comment: How will you access the variables? Why not an array?

Comment: Indeed, this seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Read the digits in a loop or store them in an array. `fold stuff | while read -r line; do : something with this "$line"; done`

Comment: @tripleee, ...well, I'd want to invert that from a pipeline to a process substitution to avoid [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024) issues, but yes.

Comment: As others have also suggested, you probably should use an array  to hold the string parts.  However, your code almost works (assuming that `input_string` has the correct value).  The problem is that the `grep` command does not match the `declare -p` output.  Maybe start with `declare -p | grep var_` and modify the `grep` options until it does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Rubberducky, ...to be a little more explicit, `\w` is PCRE syntax. `grep` supports BRE or ERE; only with nonstandard extensions can it support PCRE, and even then on the GNU version compiled with the optional library dependency adding that support there's an extra argument needed to turn it on.

Comment: Thanks all for your comments. For a bit more clarity, the string will always contain hex values with no whitespace and will always have a length of multiples of four. Once the string is split into blocks and the variables created these will then be used further to convert the hex to decimal..

Answer (score 1):

The normal approach would be to create an array of the entries, easily doable with `mapfile` (or `readarray` - a synonym of `mapfile`); in this case we'll also use process substitution to feed the `fold` results to `mapfile`, eg:

```
$ string=1234567898765432
$ mapfile -t arr < <(fold -w4 <<< "${string}")
$ typeset -p arr
declare -a arr=([0]="1234" [1]="5678" [2]="9876" [3]="5432")
```

---

The chatGPT answer is working it's just that the final line of the script (`declare -p | grep -E ...`) needs some tweaking.  Alternatives for the last line:

```
$ declare -p | grep 'var_'
declare -- var_1="1234"
declare -- var_2="5678"
declare -- var_3="9876"
declare -- var_4="5432"
declare -- var_name="var_4"           # probably don't want to see this one

$ declare -p | grep '^declare -- var_[0-9]*='
declare -- var_1="1234"
declare -- var_2="5678"
declare -- var_3="9876"
declare -- var_4="5432"

$ declare -p | grep -E ' var_[0-9]+='
declare -- var_1="1234"
declare -- var_2="5678"
declare -- var_3="9876"
declare -- var_4="5432"
```

Comment: Another Bash alternative for the last line using parameter expansion: `declare -p "${!var_@}"`

Comment: Thanks for this. The 'mapfile' suggestion works, but the output format means extra tweaks will be needed to reformat. The majority of the users simply won't entertain this :(.
Unfortunately when I run the script with the 'declare -p' entries I get the same block for each variable :(
The blocks of 4 are correct but each of the variables are output as:
declare -- var_1="2345"
declare -- var_2="2345"
declare -- var_3="2345"
declare -- var_4="2345"

Comment: the `typeset -p` (`typeset -p` and `declare -p` are interchangeable) is just my way of showing the contents of the array; I could've instead used a `for` loop with the index ranging from `0` to `${#arr[@]}-1` (the `#` gives the count of elements in the array); as for the individual variables (the output from the chatGPT code) ... how were you going to know that list to start with?

Comment: @markp-fuso, not 100% sure what you mean here. Sorry....
rather than see var_1="1234", var_2="5678", var_3="9876" etc etc it returns as var_1="2345", var_2="2345", var_3="2345"... The 'list' will always be constructed from a string which is made up of multiples of 4 characters. My need is to assign each block of 4 characters to a variable, then these variables can be used further along in the script in order to convert the blocks from hex to decimal for the users to check..

Comment: @Rubberducky ah, sorry, I didn't notice that you're talking about ***the values*** assigned to the variables; I've re-run the chatGPT code as well as my code ... both sets of code generate the correct assignments ... I'm not seeing all 4 variables set to the same string of `2345`; at this point I have to assume there's something different in your system ... different set of data, different script ... ????

Answer (score 1):

This [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)-clean pure Bash code demonstrates one way to populate an array with the 4-character blocks extracted from the input string:

```
#! /bin/bash -p

input_string=1234567898765432
blocks=()
for ((i=0; i<${#input_string}; i+=4)); do
    blocks+=( "${input_string:i:4}" )
done
declare -p blocks
```

- This should work with any version of Bash since 2.0 (released in 1996).
- It will work for `input_string` containing any possible characters (including spaces, newlines, and glob characters).